# php SOAP request sending blank elements

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm relatively inexperienced with SOAP requests and the SoapClient class. I'm trying to call a function of a web service but when I look at the request being sent, it's showing blank elements where I have supplied an array of arguments. So I'm not sure if I'm improperly reading the wsdl or what the issue is here.

This is my php:

```
$ns = 'http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0';
$response = $client->__soapCall('Login',array($loginData)); 
$clientLoginToken = $client->__getLastResponse();

//token coming back as header in soap response; strip out xml and only use the Ticket element
$clientLoginToken = strip_tags($clientLoginToken);

//need to send auth header back on subsequent requests
$soapHeader = new SoapHeader($ns,'WSAPISession',array('Ticket'=>$clientLoginToken));

//test to simply retrieve a customer record..
$customerData = array('CustomerGetByNumberRequest'=>
                     array('CustomerNumber'=>'00006195')
                );

//call CustomerGetByNumber function
$customer = $client->__soapCall('CustomerGetByNumber',
                                array($customerData),
                                null,
                                array($soapHeader),
                                $output_headers);
```

This is the outgoing XML when I call `$client->__getLastRequest()`. As you can see the `CustomerGetByNumber` element is empty even though I'm supplying the arguments to the `__soapCall()` above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.WSAPI.AMS360.com/v3.0">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:WSAPISession>
      <ns1:Ticket>
           tcyOHI65U2H1yKsuvpahvoWzViAQy+tsWRElraBgKJewSQQJFi8cgS/9bjge5TlXlzH2XkxszR5u/i42dGjUnd+0JHOlQ1bJYbY5/cLgctvn4iTqoD9NPL67S0MvG5Uq
      </ns1:Ticket>
    </ns1:WSAPISession>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CustomerGetByNumber />
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The CustomerGetByNumberRequest key was supposed to just be Request

Comment: Hi. Sorry this is off-topic, but I'm starting work on a web integration with WSAPI for AMS360, and I'm finding it difficult to find examples/documentation to work from. I'm wondering if you'd be willing to share any resources.